# Can't re-enable a view after disabling it with CheckBox

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox, seekbar

I'm trying to enable/disable a seekbar when a checkbox is checked(or not).

I'm using this to create and refer:

```
CheckBox checkBoxProva = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_prova);
boolean varCheckBoxProva = checkBoxProva.isChecked();
```

And this simple if to disable/enable the view:

```
if (!varCheckBoxProva) {
    seekBarProva.setEnabled(false);
}
```

All this is inside the onCreate.

When the app starts the seekbar is disabled (so the if works), but if I check the CheckBox it doesn't change to enabled.

EDIT: I've succed thank to the reply of @rohan bhatia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Listener that notifies when a checkbox is selected or deselected..

```
checkBoxProva.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

            seekBarProva.setEnabled(isChecked);

       }
   }
);
```

Accordingly, whenever you click the checkbox the method onCheckedChanged() will be executed.. You will still need to specify this in onCreate -

```
seekBarProva.setEnabled(checkBoxProva.isChecked());
```

As onCheckedChanged() only listens for changes in checked state, so to specify initial stage you will need that above line too.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all of this in your `onCreate` method that only gets called when the activity is first created. You need to setup a listener that will be fired when the checkbox is clicked. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html

Comment: it doesn't matter, it should still work. you can for example create a button listener in the onCreate and it should still work.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw But the OP never said they are using a listener. I think this answer is on the right lines. All we know is that they are just checking the state once.

Comment: @petehallw definitely agree. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert an `else` block

```
if (!varCheckBoxProva) {
    seekBarProva.setEnabled(false);
}else{
    seekBarProva.setEnabled(true);
}
```

**Alternative solution:**

Personally, I'd recommend adding a listener to the checkbox inside your `onCreate` method.

```
checkBoxProva.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if(varCheckBoxProva){
               seekBarProva.setEnabled(true);
           }else{
               seekBarProva.setEnabled(false);
           }
       }
});
```